# $_GET запрос некорректно работает

Tags: php, алгоритм, веб-программирование, запрос, get

Делаю самостоятельно календарь.
Используя $_GET получаю месяц и год.
потом простой вывод с помощью 'date'.

но столкнулся вот с чем.
если прокручивать назад календарь, все корректно.
Но если прокрутить вперед, то при переключении между годами переключение зависает на 1 месяце. Подскажите где я накосипорил?

```
   <form action="myURL/calendar.php" method="get" >
            <input type="hidden" name="month" value="<?php if($nowMonth==12){$nowMonth=1; $nowYear=$nowYear+1; echo $nowMonth;}else{ echo $nowMonth+1;}?>" /><br/>

            <input type="hidden" name="y" value="<?php echo $nowYear;?>" /><br/>
            <button type="submit"> > </button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Изначально не правильно сделал вывод значений.
Так как по указанному выше коду видно, что срабатывает первое присвоение, а потом второе. То есть, мы никогда не выйдем из "цикла".

Решение оказалось простым, вместо присвоения выводить просто цифры.

Вот первая часть  -

```
     if($nowMonth==12){
     $nowYear=$nowYear+1;
     }elseif ($nowMonth==1){
     $nowYear=$nowYear-1;
     }
```

а вот вторая часть

```
     <form action="myURL/calendar.php" method="get" >
<input type="hidden" name="month" value="<?php if($nowMonth==1){echo 
    12;}else {echo $nowMonth-1;}?>" /><br/>

<input type="hidden" name="y" value="<?php echo $nowYear;?>" /><br/>
<button type="submit"><</button>
    </form>
   </td>
        <td align="center" colspan="5"><h2><?php echo $monthName;?></h2>
     </td>
  <td>
<form action="myURL/calendar.php" method="get" >
    <input type="hidden" name="month" value="<?php if($nowMonth==12){echo 
     1;}else {echo $nowMonth+1;}?>" /><br/>

    <input type="hidden" name="y" value="<?php echo $nowYear;?>" /><br/>
    <button type="submit"> > </button>
</form>
```